# xelatex qrcode fails with arabic language set as default language

Tags: xetex, qrcode

First time posting sorry for any mistakes. I am trying to generate qr codes for a document using [qrcode](http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode/qrcode.pdf) package and xelatex. If the default language is set to arabic (lines 6 and 7 below) and the document run for the first time, XeLatex fails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setotherlanguage{english}\newfontfamily\englishfont{Computer Modern} % Problem Lines
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,SizeFeatures={Size=10}]{Sakkal Majalla} % Problem Lines
\begin{document}
\qrset{height=1in}
\qrcode{abcd}
\end{document}
```

If however these lines are commented out and the document run, xelatex succeeds and QR code generated. Now uncommenting lines (6 and 7) back, the QRCode is generated (but mirrored, notice in image below lower qr marker is on the right side not left).

[image]

The error message that appears is

```
<QR code requested for "abcd" in version 0-M.>
<Error-correction level increased from M to H at no cost.>
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
l.10 \qrcode{abcd}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I haven’t confirmed this, but bugs like this sometimes happen when a package incorrectly uses counters to generate labels, and a language package redefines those counters. This particularly happens when a package uses `\arabic{counter}` instead of `\thecounter` to generate a number as part of a csname.

Comment: If I got your comment correctly I should look in the package code for \arabic{... something...}? 
On line 2150 of the qrcode.sty there is \arabic{qr@i}. 
Any thoughts on how to fix it? Will changing \arabic{qr@i} with \theq@i fix it?
I will try and report it

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, qrcode uses \arabic as a number, and the arabic language redefines this. So you need to patch a qrcode command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\FX@getstringlength{\arabic{qr@i}}{\the\c@qr@i}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{english}%\newfontfamily\englishfont{Computer Modern} % Problem Lines
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,SizeFeatures={Size=10}]{Amiri} % Problem Lines
\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\qrset{height=1in}
\qrcode{abcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt Ulricke. I tried to compile your code on my machine I got the following
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \fail

l.6 ...length{\arabic{qr@i}}{\the\c@qr@i}{}{\fail}

?

Comment: Using the comment of @Davislor I chased the code for polyglossia arabic and found in the file gloss-arabic.ldf the following two code segments

Comment: I tested my code. On a current tex system it works. Perhaps you have an older qrcode package?

Comment: I don't think so, the qr package seems to be last updated 2015. and i installed tex two weeks ago.

Comment: Using \show\@arabic

> \@arabic=macro:
#1->\ifeastern@numerals \@ensure@dir {\arabicdigits {\number #1}}\else \number
#1\fi .
l.19 \show\@arabic

And in gloss-arabic.ldf

\newif\ifeastern@numerals
\def\tmp@mashriq{mashriq}
\def\tmp@maghrib{maghrib}
\define@key{arabic}{numerals}[mashriq]{%
  \def\@tmpa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tmpa\tmp@mashriq%
    \eastern@numeralstrue%
  \else
    \ifx\@tmpa\tmp@maghrib\eastern@numeralsfalse\fi%
  \fi}

Comment: I lost the selection of the english, I just edited the example. But this would not explain why you get an error from the patch. Are you sure that you tried exactly my code?

Comment: I tried on overleaf also it still does not work

Comment: show the log-file you get from my code.

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/5e1YcisB)

https://pastebin.com/5e1YcisB

Comment: I get failures like Mohanad. FWIW, I'm on a Mac.

Comment: You are using texlive 2019, I have a current 2020 system. I can try tomorrow on an older texlive, but now it is too late.

Comment: **@dedded** Did the workaround work for you?

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just uploaded a log file from TL2020 (updated just now): https://pastebin.com/CQ5GKhZ1 
That's from xelatex, but lualatex also fails.

Comment: @MohanadAhmed Yes, the workaround works (as long as I use Ulrike's font, I don't have Sakkal Majalla).

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround \setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Sakkal Majalla}

Hopefully until someone knows a better way.